# Pug (Jade) syntax highlighting not working with Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, pug, sublimetext3

After installing Pug for Sublime Text 3 and setting it to use Pug for syntax highlighting, I get the following problems:

[image]

I believe the problem is using "string"+variable without (brackets), after testing this, the next line works...

[image]
I will go through the whole file and see if I can fix all of it, and then edit this or give an answer.

Comment: Try to install the plugin here https://github.com/davidrios/pug-tmbundle it's also jade.

Comment: @headmax thanks but that is what I used.

Comment: so if you did i also suggest to see if a fork was made and try to see if someone got the same problem in a github way.

Comment: I will open this as an issue on the github page because the syntax is correct and compiles html correctly, but the syntax highlighting doesn't recognize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't like:

```
id="string"+variable
```

The correct syntax is:

```
id=("string"+variable)
```